# Magento 2 - How to get base URL in layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3.4

I need to add the livereload script which listens on a certain port, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="http://www.example.com:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>
</head>
```

How can I add the base URL instead of `www.example.com` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, Its worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
    <script src="{{baseUrl}}:35729/livereload.js" src_type="url"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatelly it renders it as `http://www.example.com/:35729/livereload.js` instead of `http://www.example.com:35729/livereload.js`